# Python: Fastest way to search if long string is in list of strings

Tags: python, search

I have an input of about 2-5 millions strings of about 400 characters each, coming from a stored text file.
I need to check for duplicates before adding them to the list that I check (doesn't have to be a list, can be any other data type, the list is technically a set since all items are unique).

I can expect about 0.01% at max of my data to be non-unique and I need to filter them out.

I'm wondering if there is any faster way for me to check if the item exists in the list rather than:

```
a=[]
for item in data:
    if item not in a:
        a.add(item)
```

I do not want to lose the order.

Would hashing be faster (I don't need encryption)? But then I'd have to maintain a hash table for all the values to check first.
Is there any way I'm missing?

I'm on python 2, can at max go upto python 3.5.

Comment: It it fits in RAM, `a = set(data)` is as fast as you're likely to get.  It it doesn't fit in RAM, you need to say so.  Sets use hash codes under the covers, so don't go reinventing that yourself ;-)

Comment: Sets already use hashing.  I would honestly just use `a=set(data)` (note you don't need to explicitly iterate over the data).

If this is still too slow for you, you may need to consider not using Python, though be aware that Python is not particularly slow for this sort of thing.

Comment: It fits in RAM.

Comment: It might be relevant to tell us what your data source is.  There's a good chance you will be limited by I/O in any case.

Comment: Data source is a stored text file.

Comment: To keep the order, use `a = dict.fromkeys(data)` in a recent version of Python (dicts officially maintain insertion order as of Python 3.7, and unofficially since 3.6).  Sets do not.

Comment: In Python 2 you can do `a = OrderedDict.fromkeys(data)` after `from collections import OrderedDict`.  But you may have to reevaluate whether it still fits in RAM then, because `OrderedDict` isn't "lean".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer this question because it keeps changing ;-)  The version I'm answering asks whether there's a faster way than:

```
a=[]
for item in data:
    if item not in a:
        a.add(item)
```

That will be horridly slow, taking time quadratic in `len(data)`.  In any version of Python the following will take expected-case time linear in `len(data)`:

```
seen = set()
for item in data:
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
        emit(item)
```

where `emit()` does whatever you like (append to a list, write to a file, whatever).

In comments I already noted ways to achieve the same thing with ordered dictionaries (whether ordered by language guarantee in Python 3.7, or via the `OrderedDict` type from the `collections` package).  The code just above is the most memory-efficient, though.

Comment: I tried with seen={} and seen[item]=None and it was 1.5% faster.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,

```
a = list(set(data))
```

A List is an ordered sequence of elements whereas Set is a distinct list of elements which is unordered.

Comment: You will lose the ordering by going through a Set though.